# How to display Android splash screen correctly in NativeScript?

Tags: android, nativescript, splash-screen

I am working on a major project in NativeScript. It seems to be impossible to get the splash screen display correctly on Android landscape.

**If I launch the app in portrait,** the portrait splash image appears correctly. If I turn it sideways before the app launches, the splash image rotates, but it's not replaced by the landscape image. Now the oversized portrait image covers about half of the screen on the left, the other half is black. The image is not stretched, the proportion is correct, but it's larger than the screen and overflows it.

**If I launch the app in landscape,** it loads the portrait image and stretches it to fit the screen. In a few seconds, regardless if I turn it or not, it switches to portrait mode and rotates the image, but still stretched.

All the assets are in place and are correct.

I've tried playing with `AndroidManifest.xml`, here it is:
https://pastebin.com/BRCx5a96

Any idea appreciated.

Comment: Have used onConfigurationChanged function?

Comment: Sounds like something, but I've never tried tinkering with app.gradle. I'm not into Java at all. I'll look it up, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's cause is your image resolutions(in App_Resources). Try [Images](http://images.nativescript.rocks/index.php) in NativeScript Rocks and create your splash screen and other things here.